# Create table with CTE in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have  a query where is it possible to use create table with CTE? As i cannot create any new table in my database. I am trying to calculate business days and number of business days elapsed excluding holidays and weekends. But this create table is not working. If there is any way to do it? Due to this create table i am not getting back any results.

```
create table holidays(holiday date)
insert holidays values ('11-22-2018'),('11-23-2018')

;with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    convert(date,getdate()) as today
)
,holidaycount as (
    select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
        sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
    from dates
    join holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
)
,daycounts as(
    select dates.*,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, endofmonth) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, endofmonth) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofmonth) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaysinmonth,0) as wkdaysinmonth,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, today) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, today) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaystodate,0) as wkdaystodate

    from dates
    cross join holidaycount
) 

select * from daycounts
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Used_By_Already..just testing it..and it didn't work :(...is there any way to just subtract 22nd November from daycounts table? and not to do separate holiday and create table thing?

Comment: Well: declare a table variable? use a temp table? use another cte?

Comment: @Used_By_Already..Maybe use another cte if possible..but no idea how to do it..any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a table variable:

```
declare @holidays table (holiday date)
insert @holidays values ('11-22-2018'),('11-23-2018')

;with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    convert(date,getdate()) as today
)
,holidaycount as (
    select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
        sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
    from dates
    join @holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
)
```

Using a cte:

```
;with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    convert(date,getdate()) as today
), holidays as (
    select holiday
    from (values ('11-22-2018'),('11-23-2018') ) x (holiday)
 )
,holidaycount as (
    select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
        sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
    from dates
    join holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
)
```

Be cautious of date literals, you are assuming that the database will accept dd-mm-yyyy strings as dates. This might not be always true, so, instead use YYYYMMDD which SQL Server will understand as dates, or next best is YYYY-MM-DD.